# disable error pages in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to TOTALLY disable the twig error pages in Symfony. I do not want to customize them as described here: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html but rather simply unplug the exception handling mechanism of twig and end up with plain good old php errors.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: If I may be so bold as to ask why you want to go with native php errors? Errors should never be displayed to the user, and during dev/QA you should run in an environment that shows the rrors

Comment: I just hate em. I am more confy with ugly messages that's it. ANy idea how to do it?

Comment: You might have better luck using only some of the symfoyn components, instead of the whole package. you can read up on the components here http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/index.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To disable twig error pages you can just add something like

```
services:
   twig.exception_listener:
     class: DateTime #or another dummy class
```

to your app/config.yml

After this you will see much simple screen produced by Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\ExceptionHandler. If you want to remove this behavior - replace this class or just comment set_exception_handler call in.

```
public static function register($debug = true)
{
    $handler = new static($debug);

    set_exception_handler(array($handler, 'handle'));

    return $handler;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Symfony 3.x, this is how it can be done:

To **services.yml**, add the listener override (as in @Ziumin's answer):

```
services:
  twig.exception_listener:
    class: stdObject
```

In **app_dev.php**, comment out the line `Debug::enable();`, which will disable even the simplified error handling page (and then there's no need to modify files from the framework).

Then after that, you can add your own exception handler:

```
// Disable error handling page:
// Debug::enable();

set_exception_handler(function($e) {
    $msg = array();
    $msg[] = 'Exception: ' . $e->getMessage() . ' at ' . $e->getFile() . ':' . $e->getLine();
    $msg[] = '';
    $msg[] = $e->getTraceAsString();
    echo implode("\n", $msg);
});
```